# Webpack / React/ Spring Boot: caching bundle.js with https

Tags: reactjs, caching, spring-boot, https, webpack

In my Spring-Boot/React application, i want to cache `bundle.js`(1.2Mb). If i run the app with `http://(test-envionment-server-url)/myapp`, my `bundle.js` get called from cache (208 B) with HTTP status 304 every time i refresh the page. Until now everything is fine.

But when i use `https://(test-envionment-server-url)/myapp`, `bundle.js` is not cached and each time i refresh it gets all 1.2Mb, yet all other images and font get cached.

I am using Tomcat in local, and JBoss 7.0.x in my test environment.

Here is my `webpack.config.js`

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
  cache: true,
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8008',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    'babel-polyfill',
    './src/index.js',
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'react-hot!babel',
    },
    {
      test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
      loaders: [
        'url?limit=2048',
        'img',
      ],
    },
    {
      test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/,
      loader: 'url-loader?limit=2048',
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: ['style', 'css', 'postcss-loader', 'sass'],
    },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  output: {
    path:`${__dirname}/(spring-boot-app-url/resources/static`,
    publicPath: '/publicpath/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 8008,
    contentBase: './dist',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    proxy: {
      .....(proxy config)
    },
  },
},
},
postcss: () => {
  return [autoprefixer];
},
plugins: [
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
  },
}),
],
};
```

in my Spring i have some Spring security configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity

            .csrf().disable()

            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(TOKEN_NAME).permitAll() // API
            ...(antMatchers)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT).permitAll();

    httpSecurity
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl().disable();
}
```

Here is the Request header from my Network tab:

```
 Accept:*/*
 Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
 Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
 Connection:keep-alive
 Host:*****
 Referer:https://****/appname/
 User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36
```

Here is the Response header from Network tab:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:max-age=3600
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1248915
Content-Type:application/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 05 Dec 2016 12:56:47 GMT
Last-Modified:Mon, 05 Dec 2016 09:08:06 GMT
Server:JBoss-EAP/7
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-Powered-By:Undertow/1
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

When i run it with **http** url, the header request doesn't have any cache control.
Any idea about how to cache `bundle.js` file even when i run my app using **https**?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us the request and response HTTP headers for this particular resource?

Comment: i added the https request and response headers, the difference between them and http, is that Cache-control is added for https.

Comment: How did you get those headers? Did you have a "disable cache" option set in your browser or did you refresh your browser tab with "ctrl+R"? If not, `Cache-Control:max-age=0` implies that the problem comes from your client and that the server behaves properly.

Comment: i got those headers, from chrome devtools,i did refresh my browser with ctrl+R

Comment: can you get the same information with `curl -vv https://YOUR_URL/bundle.js` ?

Comment: i added the response

Comment: You're getting an SSL error because of your self-signed certificate. Can you try with `curl -vv --insecure https://YOUR_URL/bundle.js`

Comment: i added the respnse...any idea where does the problem come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the provided HTTP response, it seems your server is not sending the appropriate Cache-Control headers. Doing so can cause issues when you're changing the contents of your static resource.

This is why you should:

- configure a `Cache-Control` header to be sent when serving static resources
- configure a resource chain with a content strategy ([see here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content))

The overall configuration **for your production profile** should look like:

```
spring.resources.cache-period=3600 # caching resources for 1 hour
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.enabled=true
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.paths=/**
```

Comment: now in the bundle response i see Cache-Control:max-age=3600, but it still loads the hole 1.2 Mb file

Comment: then don't refresh using "ctrl+R" and uncheck the "disable cache" option in the chrome devtools network tab. Doing those sends a "Cache-Control: max-age=0" to the server and forces the re-download of the resource. Without those, you'll see that the resource is loaded from your cache.

Comment: i really should thank you for your time answering my stupid questions. The objective is when i refresh i don't want the server to re-download the resource. How can i check that the resource is loaded from cache as i still see 1.2Mb and not (loaded from disk cache) or 208B as it is displayed with http. Can you please clarify more ?

Comment: open chrome devtools without the "disable cache" option, then hit enter in the browser address bar - you should see the expected behavior in the network tab. Hitting ctrl+R will force a redownload, that's not what you want.

Comment: yes i see all resources loaded from memory cache, except my bundle.js file :/

Comment: please update your question with the request and response headers you can get from the network tab for that resource

Comment: i did the update, could it be because it is not hashed ? because all my other resources (jpeg/png) are hashed ?

Comment: please update your question with any Spring Boot web configuration (property keys, web configuration classes), your project layout (where is this file located).

Comment: Are those files all served by Spring Boot? Or is the bundle served by another server (different port?)

Comment: bundle.js is the output of my front-end, as you see in my webpack config, the bundle.js path is served by webpack to my spring boot app/ resources/static

Comment: the problem was in JBoss configuration, i added gzip compression properties. Thank you very much

Comment: Well gzipping has nothing to do with this resource being cached; so what did solve the real issue here?

Comment: i added also the configuration you suggested in my file properties, but bundle.js wasn't being cached, even if in the response i see Cache-control : max-age=3600, after i added gzip compression properties it was loaded from memory cache

Answer (score 1):

the problem was in my JBoss Configuration:

in standalone.xml i added gzip compression properties :

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION" value="on"/>
    <property name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION_MIME_TYPES" value="text/javascript,text/css,text/html,application/xml,application/json"/>
    <property name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION_MIN_SIZE" value="1024"/>
</system-properties>
```

right under extensions.